# How to display DataGrid to XML file?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

I have a requirement that when I click on GeneratXML button which is below the DataGrid the Datagrid data is converted in one xml file.

Comment: What kind of data is in your `DataGrid` and what is the target format (or XML schema) you need to generate?

Comment: Actually I have a User Information form which contains Username,Address(City),& Gender and Add & Reset button.when I click on Add button The data will be display in  datagrid and The dataGrid Page contains Datagrid and one GenerateXML button and when I click on GenerateXML button the all data in DataGrid will display in xml file format.The DataGrid also have Delete and Edit option links.when I click on edit link the userInformation page opens with update button instead of add button.

Comment: So, you're saying you don't know how to iterate through your own data provider to create XML?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would do I think - (I don't know what your data is like, its a two sentence question)  ;)

```
private function getDataProviderXML ( dp :ArrayCollection ) :String {
    var full :String = '<root>';
    for each ( var o :Object in dp ){
        full += '<row>';
        for each ( var prop :String in o ){
            full += '<' + prop + '>' + o[prop] + '</' + prop + '>' 
        }
        full += '</row>';
    }
    return full += '</root>'; 
}
```

Comment: Ugly. Why can't you just use the XML object that's make to append children and create a proper string?

Comment: For something as simple as less than 10 lines (for a 2 sentence question mind you)?  Really?  In other news, should you actually post an example rather than raising your nose at mine, performance test the two and get back to me with the results.